# Repetitive event handler for a toggling UI control

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, animation

I feel like this bit of code could have been written more elegantly, especially with the huge if/else statements. Can somebody help me break this down? It would really help me out in the future.

```
// Contact
var c = 0;
var contactHeight = $('#contact-keebs').outerHeight();
$('#mail-wrap').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (c++ % 2 == 0) {

        $('#contact-button').addClass('project-button').css('width', '71px').text('Projects');
        $('.mail-icon').attr('src', site.theme_path + '/img/icon-projects.png');
        $('#contact-button').shuffleLetters({callback:function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop : 0
                },200, function() {
                    $('#contact-keebs').fadeIn(200);
                    $('body').css({
                        height   : contactHeight,
                        overflow : 'hidden'
                    });
                    $('#contact-info, #clients').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                });
            } else {
                $('#contact-keebs').fadeIn(200);
                $('body').css({
                    height   : contactHeight,
                    overflow : 'hidden'
                });
                $('#contact-info, #clients').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            }
        }
        });

    } else {

        $('#contact-button').removeClass('project-button').css('width', '96px').text('Get in touch');
        $('.mail-icon').attr('src', site.theme_path + '/img/icon-contact.png');
        $('#contact-button').shuffleLetters({callback:function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop : 0
                },200, function() {
                    $('#contact-info, #clients').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
                    $('body').css({
                        height   : '',
                        overflow : ''
                    });
                    $('#contact-keebs').fadeOut(200);
                });
            } else {
                $('#contact-info, #clients').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
                $('body').css({
                    height   : '',
                    overflow : ''
                });
                $('#contact-keebs').fadeOut(200);
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML**

// Button

```
<div id="mail-wrap">
    <div class="icon-wrap">
        <img class="mail-icon" src="img/icon-contact.png" alt="Contact" height="26" width="24">
    </div>
    <a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>
</div>
```

// Contact section

```
<div id="contact-keebs">
    <span class="contact-overlay"></span>
    <div id="contact-wrapper">
        <div id="contact-info">
            <h1>Title statement</h1>
            <h2>Email</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="clients">
            <h2>Clients &amp; Partners</h2>
            <ul id="client-list">
                <li>Client 1</li>
                <li>Client 2</li>
                <li>Client 3</li>
                <li>Client 4</li>
                <li>Client 5</li>
                <li>Client 6</li>
                <li>Client 7</li>
                <li>Client 8</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Contact
var contactHeight = $('#contact-keebs').outerHeight();

function in_keebs() {
    $('#contact-keebs').fadeIn(200);
    $('body').css({
        height   : contactHeight,
        overflow : 'hidden'
    });
    $('#contact-info, #clients').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
}

function out_keebs() {
    $('#contact-info, #clients').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
    $('body').css({
        height   : '',
        overflow : ''
    });
    $('#contact-keebs').fadeOut(200);
}

function show_project_button(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#contact-button').addClass('project-button').css('width', '71px').text('Projects');
    $('.mail-icon').attr('src', site.theme_path + '/img/icon-projects.png');
    $('#contact-button').shuffleLetters({callback:function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop : 0
            },200, in_keebs);
        } else {
            in_keebs();
        }
    }
    });

    $('#mail-wrap').click(hide_project_button);
}

function hide_project_button(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#contact-button').removeClass('project-button').css('width', '96px').text('Get in touch');
    $('.mail-icon').attr('src', site.theme_path + '/img/icon-contact.png');
    $('#contact-button').shuffleLetters({callback:function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop : 0
            },200, out_keebs);
        } else {
            out_keebs();
        }
    }
    });

    $('#mail-wrap').click(show_project_button);
}

$('#mail-wrap').click(show_project_button);
```

First, I'm not at all convinced that these are the right function names, but I needed names and these at least seem somewhat related.  Part of the problem is that I don't really understand what you're doing, as I don't know what the underlying HTML is.

The insight to get rid of the outer `if`/`else` is that you are simply alternating between them.  Instead of using a variable for tracking, we change the `onclick` behavior at the end of each variant.  We pick one and start with it.  This gives us the same alternating behavior as the `if`/`else` did.  We can also get rid of `c`.

We're still stuck with the inner `if`/`else` blocks, but we can remove the repeated code into their own functions.

Note that I haven't tested this, as I don't have enough context to run it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going over the code now. Also, I updated the original post with the HTML as well as a live example for you if it helps at all. Thanks again, I will try to understand your code.

Comment: One thing I noticed was that when I click on the button once, then click it again, the 'Get in Touch' text is supposed to appear. However, it still stays on 'Projects' and `#contact-wrapper` doesn't fade out.

Comment: @Desi  Do you have a test page where the JavaScript is not minimized?